# Error with rendering a sorted array in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to render an array of items based on their value (highest to lowest). Everything works fine but I am getting an error saying `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.` whenever I run the code. Below is the code used to sort through the array `items` and map out each item based on its value. I am not sure how to prevent this error.

```js
const items = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Topic 1', value: 2},
    {id: 2, title: 'Topic 2', value: 5},
    {id: 3, title: 'Topic 3', value: 1},
    {id: 4, title: 'Topic 4', value: 4},
    {id: 5, title: 'Topic 5', value: 3},
]

const App = () => {
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full p-6 items-center">

    {items.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value).map((item, index) => (
        <div 
            className="flex gap-2 px-4 items-center h-10 w-full rounded-md text-lg bg-[#ffd700]"
            key={index}
        >
            <div>
                {item.title}
                {item.value}
            </div>
            /5
        </div>
     ))}

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers; the error can be fixed simply by including the list of whatever you are trying to sort inside of the main function.

For example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const items = [
        {id: 1, title: 'Topic 1', value: 2},
        {id: 2, title: 'Topic 2', value: 5},
        {id: 3, title: 'Topic 3', value: 1},
        {id: 4, title: 'Topic 4', value: 4},
        {id: 5, title: 'Topic 5', value: 3},
    ]

    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full p-6 items-center">

    {items.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value).map((item, index) => (
        <div 
            className="flex gap-2 px-4 items-center h-10 w-full rounded-md text-lg bg-[#ffd700]"
            key={index}
        >
            <div>
                {item.title}
                {item.value}
            </div>
            /5
        </div>
     ))}

    </div>
}
```

Comment: This problem made me lose a few hours and it doesn't make sense to me that it has a DOM order mismatch if you render an array declared outside a React Component versus declared inside. Can't find any info about this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.sort()` mutates the original array. You can fix this by cloning the array and sort that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Even cloning an array does not help (which I don't understand, used array.slice() still haveing issues).
If you don't want to define all your helper functions inside your component (which you shouldn't imho), you do all manipulations on server side in the first place or you put the array in state.

```
'use client'
const Home = ({arrayFromServer}) => {
  const [arrayOnClient, setArrayOnClient] = useState();
  useEffect( 
    if(!arrayFromServer) { return }
    setArrayOnClient([...arrayFromServer]) // spread just to be sure
  }
  const arrayManipulated = arrayOnClient? arrayOnClient.sort(
      externalSortingFn.call(this, a, b)
  ) : ... // do something usefull here.
}
```

cases like this should be documented more clearly!

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is due to the fact that you are using `(` instead of `{` in the `.map` function.
The correct syntax of the `.map` function is:

```js
items.map((item, index) => {
  return <>...</>
})
```

Your example would work with this:

```js
const items = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Topic 1', value: 2},
    {id: 2, title: 'Topic 2', value: 5},
    {id: 3, title: 'Topic 3', value: 1},
    {id: 4, title: 'Topic 4', value: 4},
    {id: 5, title: 'Topic 5', value: 3},
]

<div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full p-6 items-center">

    {items.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value).map((item, index) => {
        <div 
            className="flex gap-2 px-4 items-center h-10 w-full rounded-md text-lg bg-[#ffd700]"
            key={index}
        >
            <div>
                {item.title}
                {item.value}
            </div>
            /5
        </div>
     })}

</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is still showing after making these changes.

Comment: using `(foo) => (...)` is perfectly valid for an arrow function that has a single expression you're putting over multiple lines, and it avoids the need for an explicit return.